# Convert string to date with format 2020-04-21T11:28:40.321328+00:00

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

im working with spark structured streaming, with pyspark.

I have a string with this format:

`2020-04-21T11:28:40.321328+00:00`

I need to change to the date format with this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, im trying do this:

`date_format(to_timestamp('value.Ticker.time', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssssssZ"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

But the result is null:

My code is:

```
BytesDF_Data_Level_2 = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "data_level_2") \
  .load()

StringDF_Data_Level_2 = BytesDF_Data_Level_2.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
JsonDF_Data_Level_2 = StringDF_Data_Level_2.withColumn("value", from_json("value", schema_data_level_II))
JsonDF_cols_Data_Level_2 = JsonDF_Data_Level_2.select(
    #col('value.Ticker.contract.Forex.tradingClass'),
    col('value.Ticker.time'),
    date_format(to_timestamp('value.Ticker.time', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssssssZ"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    #col('value.Ticker.bid'),
    #col('value.Ticker.bidSize'),
    #col('value.Ticker.ask'),
    #col('value.Ticker.askSize')
    )

query = JsonDF_cols_Data_Level_2.\
    writeStream\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .format("console") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`to_timestamp`** (or) **`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`** functions with format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`

```
df.withColumn("new_time", to_timestamp(col("time"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).show(10,False)
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
#|time                            |new_time           |
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
#|2020-04-21T11:28:40.321328+00:00|2020-04-21 11:28:40|
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+

#using date_format
df.withColumn("new_time", date_format(to_timestamp(col("time"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).show(10,False)
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
#|time                            |new_time           |
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
#|2020-04-21T11:28:40.321328+00:00|2020-04-21 11:28:40|
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+

#using from_unixtime, unix_timestamp functions
df.withColumn("new_time", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("time"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).show(10,False)
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
#|time                            |new_time           |
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
#|2020-04-21T11:28:40.321328+00:00|2020-04-21 11:28:40|
#+--------------------------------+-------------------+
```

---

**`For Spark-3:`**

```
df.withColumn("new_time",to_timestamp((col('time').substr(1, 19)) ,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).show(10,False)
```

Comment: @SergioLopez, weird.. Did you try `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp)`? and which `version` of spark are you using?

Comment: my version of spark is 3.
I got it with the following code: `to_timestamp( (col('value.Ticker.time').substr(1, 19) ) ,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").alias("Fecha y hora")`

Comment: @SergioLopez, I tried code in `Spark-1.6 & Spark-2.4` but it seems `Spark-3` approach is little different. Thanks for sharing..!